# HTML IDs for rows of a Pandas Dataframe.to_html() output

Tags: python, html, pandas

I'm trying to style some rows of a Pandas Dataframe a certain way (depending on an external factor) using `df.to_html()` and some CSS rules, but is there a way to give rows HTML IDs using Pandas, or will I have to deal with the raw HTML output of `to_html()`.

More details:
I have a Pandas Dataframe that is the result of an SQL query. It will be compared with previous query results and the table will be sent out as an email. I want to highlight the rows of the dataframe that are new. I'm thinking of doing this by inserting CSS rules that either apply to the IDs of specific rows in the resultant HTML table, or by attaching a class to these rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.to_html()` `classes` keyword [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) to attach classes to the `<table></table>` tag. If you need `id` instead of `class`, you could fix the output with `df.to_html(classes='my_class').replace('class', 'id')`.

With brand new version `0.17.1`, `pandas` received `conditional html formatting` that allows more fine-grained layout control - under development: [see docs.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/style.html#style).

In particular, the [slicing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/style.html#Finer-Control:-Slicing) functionality sounds like what you are looking for to highlight specific `rows`. `ipython` notebook with documentation and interactive examples: [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/pydata/pandas/blob/master/doc/source/html-styling.ipynb)

For more complicated adjustments beyond the `<table>` level there is always [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), but that's of course ex-post and not part of `pandas`.

Comment: Whoa, slicing is exactly what I'm looking for! I'm probably not going to use it for this specific job (because it's under development and I need something stable for work), but if I need this going forward, I'm hitting it up. Thanks!

Comment: I just have to say, having to do a find/replace on `to_html` is the primary work-around I have seen... but there really shouldn't be a work-around since `id`s in HTML are pretty common.  And since this is an HTML-related function, you'd think it would have this OBVIOUSLY built in... but no.